# Class without subclassing NSObject in Swift

Tags: swift

Anyone can tell me when we can create a class without subclassing NSObject?

Comment: *With*: access to the ObjC runtime. *Without*: no access.

Answer (score 0):

> "`NSObject` is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. Through `NSObject`, objects inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects."

As this would suggest, you need to subclass `NSObject` for types introduced in your code whenever instances of that type need to behave like an Objective-C object (or the class itself, in some rarer cases).